# Angular2 with JQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, angular2-routing

Use **Datatables** in `Angular2`

I need to display the data in data table in Angular2 component. For that I to install [datatables.net](http://datatables.net) and [datatables.net.bs](http://datatables.net.bs) My Previous question is [Angular2 with Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118144/angular2-with-datatables). I am using the `angular2-routing` for navigation. 
In that previous question even on routing also this error occurs.

> Currently While using routing there is no error. It works perfectly.
>   But I have 2 errors when the browser reloads
>
> 1. Cannot reinitialize datatable
> 2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

My Updated `code` is

```
        ngOnInit() {
        this._userService.getUsers()
                .then(
                    userDetailsListVOs => {this.userDetailsListVOs = userDetailsListVOs,
this.viewUserDetails()},error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
      }

      viewUserDetails(){
           if (this.tableWidget) {
                this.tableWidget.destroy();
            }
            this.tableOptions = {
                data: this.userDetailsListVOs,
                columns: [
                    { title: 'ULA ID', data: 'ulaId',className: 'all'},
                    { title: 'City', data: 'city',className: 'none',sorting: false },
                    { title: 'Actions',data: 'data',className: 'all',sorting: false,
                    render: function ( row,type,data,meta) {
                         var edit = "<a [routerLink]=['/edit-profile',"+data.ulaId+"]><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit </a>"
                         var view = " [routerLink]=['/view-profile',"+data.ulaId+"]"
                        return `<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn green btn-xs btn-outline dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Tools<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i></button>
                                <ul class='dropdown-menu pull-right'><li><a href="/edit-profile/` + data.ulaId + `"class="actionEdit"]><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit </a></li>
                                <li><a href="/view-profile/` + data.ulaId + `"class="actionView"]><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> View </a></li>
</ul></div>`;
}}
],
                rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any | Object, index: number) => {
                    $('.actionView', row).unbind('click');
                    $('.actionView', row).bind('click', (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        this.router.navigate(['/view-profile', data.ulaId]);
                    });
                    $('.actionEdit', row).unbind('click');
                    $('.actionEdit', row).bind('click', (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        this.router.navigate(['/edit-profile', data.ulaId]);
                    });
                    return row;
                }

            }
            this.shipmentsTable = $(this._elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('table'));
            this.tableWidget = this.shipmentsTable.DataTable(this.tableOptions);
            this.tableWidget.on('select', (e, dt, type, indexes) => {
                this.userDetailsListVOs1.emit(this.userDetailsListVOs[indexes[0]]);
            });
      }
```

My Html Code is

```
<table class="table dt-responsive" id="sample_1"></table>
```

I have 2 errors

[image: reinitalize error]

and

[image: adatasort error]
Pl.Help me to solve

Comment: It is called multiple times, try `this.tableWidget = this.tableWidget || this.shipmentsTable.DataTable(this.tableOptions);` instead. But again, look at Angular DataTables...DataTables without directives is doomed to cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It really works

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?